# Particle Effects Start Glitching out

Tags: unity, particles

My particle effects have gone crazy look:

In my game, bombs drop on castle and then explode

For the first few second of my game the particle effects for the explosion works.  The particle effects are made using the unity particle systems:

As you can see below, the particle effects in the scene view are also in the game view:

[image: Explosion1]

However after a few second the particle effects start to glitch out and while they appear in the scene view, they do not appear in the game view:

[image: Explosion 2]

Above there is a massive explosion in the scene view but nothing in the game view.

I can make the particle effects work by doing a few weird things:

If I remove the walls on my castle the particles will suddenly work.  The walls just contain a sprite renderer component, no script or anything.

If I make a looping particle effect when the effect is visible on the game screen the particle effects start working but when I drag it off the screen  even though its still working(I see it in the scene view) because its not in the game screen my explosion particle effects instantly stop working.

I am super confused about why this is happening.

Comment: Is `the position.z` the same on all? It could be that the camera the game is using is clipping them.

Comment: @McAden I don't think that is the case, because if I add a looping particle effect to the scene (within the camera boundaries), everything seems to work.  I ended up hiding one behind the castle to fix this problem.